# Is it appropriate to use Kruskal-Wallis test for one comparison and Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test for another?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a data set that I would like to perform several tests on to see if there are significant changes over time. 
I have replicated measures of 3 experimental ponds and 1 control pond that I have taken different diversity measures of and would like to asses how they change over time (the sampling time is not at even intervals). 
My plan was to use the Kruskal-Wallis-nemenyi pairwise test with the PMCMR r package to see if the 3 experimental ponds' diversity changes when compared to each time point.
Next I planned to perform a paired pairwise Wilcoxon signed rank test on each individual pond to check if there is a change in the diversity at the individual level.

My question is if this is an appropriate strategy or if I should keep with using the Kruskal-Wallis tests.